# In Django is it possible to create a variable containing js in a view and then use it in a cycle template tag

Tags: javascript, django

I've been trying to create a variable in view that contains google ads code and include in my django cycle template tag so I can display and ad horizontally

```
 {% cycle "" "" "" "" "" "<div id='ad' class='col-xs-12 col-lg-12'></div>" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "<div class='col-sm-12'></div></div><div class='row'>" %}
```

I know this is long but I don't know any other way than the way I'm doing it.

I tried this

```
div1 = """<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                            <!-- responsive -->
                            <ins class=""
                            style="display:block"
                            data-ad-client=""
                            data-ad-slot=""
                            data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
                            <script>
                            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                            </script>"""
```

and then put it in between the div in the cycle tag

```
       {% cycle "" "" "" "" "" "<div id='ad' class='col-xs-12 col-lg-12'>div</div>" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "<div class='col-sm-12'></div></div><div class='row'>" %}
```

but this doesn't work inside cycle template tag

Comment: As noted in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082564/django-cycle-template-wont-allow-for-a-new-line-if-i-do-my-html-looks-scrambled) you asked, a cycle tag probably isn't the way to do this. Use `forloop.counter` instead.

Comment: you can quickly create your own tag where you can put your logic, there are few ready modules you can use (they define template tags too)

Answer (score 0):

[cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) tag works inside a for loop, iterating through each value in a loop iteration. I tried your code in a loop and it seems to work.

```
  {% for i in some_iterable %}
     {% cycle "" "" "<div id='ad' class='col-xs-12 col-lg-12'></div>" ... %}
  {% endfor %}
```

In this piece of code, the first & second value of `i` would output nothing, the 3rd will output `div#ad` and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I need the div1 variable to be inside of the cycle template tag like so <div id='ad' class='col-xs-12 col-lg-12'>div1</div> see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082564/django-cycle-template-wont-allow-for-a-new-line-if-i-do-my-html-looks-scrambled)

Comment: Can you write your expected HTML output

Comment: I edited my code above@NateJ I just want to include my javascript in side the div located within the cycle tag so I'm able to display my google ads in an horizontal banner